# Enter-PSSession Centos To Windows

Tags: powershell, remote-access, powershell-remoting, winrm

Using PowerShell version 6.0.2 on Centos 7, trying to get Session to Windows 2012 Server.
Doing the following:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force

$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("domain\username", $secpasswd)

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Some-Host-Name -port 5985 -Credential $mycreds
```

Getting the Following Error:

```
 Enter-PSSession : MI_RESULT_ACCESS_DENIED                                                                                       At line:1 char:2
+  Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Some-Host-Name -port 5985 -Credential $m ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Some-Host-Name :String) [Enter-PSSession], PSInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

Should get session to the Windows Machine.

Done the following in order the Windows machine will trust the centos machine

```
Set-Item WSMAN:\Localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value * -Force
```

Any ideas what I need to do?

Comment: Is your CentOS host have the Windows host on the TrustedHosts list?  They need to be on the same domain otherwise, using Kerberos for authentication/authorization.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Yes. Done the following command : Set-Item WSMAN:\Localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value * -Force

Comment: Have you done that on both ends?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 1. Why should the centos needs to add the windows machine to trust list if he tries to connect?
2. How Should I do it?

Comment: Because it's a client configuration, not a server configuration.  In this case, your CentOS is a client.  You can accomplish it the same way you did for your Windows box.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Added All Configuration to etc\hosts.allow file, still the same error

Comment: You should run `Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value *`.  Unsure why you changed your hosts file

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 This command does not exists in Centos...

Comment: PowerShell Core doesn't implement `Set-Item` or the `WSMan:` drive on Linux?  If that's the case, I don't have knowledge to assist further.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SSH for remoting from Linux to Windows. This is covered on the MS docs site.

> PowerShell Remoting Over SSH
>
> Overview
>
> PowerShell remoting normally uses WinRM for connection negotiation and
> data transport. SSH was chosen for this remoting implementation since
> it is now available for both Linux and Windows platforms and allows
> true multiplatform PowerShell remoting. However, WinRM also provides a
> robust hosting model for PowerShell remote sessions which this
> implementation does not yet do. And this means that PowerShell remote
> endpoint configuration and JEA (Just Enough Administration) is not yet
> supported in this implementation.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-6
>
> Getting Started with PowerShell Core on Windows, Mac, and Linux What
> do I need?
>
> To get started with PowerShell Core you want to install and configure
> these three items on your operating system(s) of choice: • PowerShell
> Core 6 Beta • OpenSSH • Visual Studio Code
>
> I was surprised how quickly I was up-and-running following the
> installation instructions. Each process involved relatively little
> tweaking for a beta experience.
>
> If you are a Linux person you might be thinking, “OK. I already have
> OpenSSH installed.” Please read the OpenSSH link above for the step of
> editing the sshd_config file for PowerShell remoting support.
>
> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/06/09/getting-started-with-powershell-core-on-windows-mac-and-linux
>
> Or see also these answers:
>
> Managing Windows Powershell from Linux terminal
>
> https://serverfault.com/questions/638659/managing-windows-powershell-from-linux-terminal
>
> How to Setup Linux to Query Windows WinRM Hosts
>
> http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/setup-linux-to-query-windows-winrm-hosts,1-3468.html